# Compiling C extensions in dep_selector Ruby gem with Rake on FreeBSD

Tags: rubygems, rake, freebsd, extconf.rb

I am trying to install Ruby gem: `dep_gecode`. It compiles some C extensions, but the compilation fails because the cpp compiler isn't run with properly set include folders.

When I run `rake install` it automatically creates a Makefile from `extconf.rb` to compile the extensions. When I edit the Makefile and manually add flag `-I/usr/local/include` the compilation of the extensions succeeds. But when I re-run `rake install` the Makefile gets overwritten and compilation fails again. Obviously I need to fix `extconf.rb` but I don't quite know how.

Now a bit more details. The source for `dep_gecode` gem is here:

https://github.com/opscode/dep-selector

The `extconf.rb` file that needs to be changed is here:

https://github.com/opscode/dep-selector/blob/master/ext/dep_gecode/extconf.rb

What I want to change in the generated Makefile is this line:

```
CPPFLAGS =  -I/usr/include   -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include
```

instead of this one, which is being generated at this moment:

```
CPPFLAGS =  -I/usr/include   -I/usr/include
```

As you see, the include path `/usr/local/include` is missing. This is a standard include path on FreeBSD systems, which suggests that the problem may be with Rake, not with this particular `extconf.rb` file.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Edit: I've just found a workaround. It is enough to add this line to `extconf.rb` to have that folder properly appearing in the generated `Makefile`:

```
$CPPFLAGS << "-I/usr/local/include"
```

Not sure if this would be the right way of dealing with this problem though...